# Send Apple Push Notifications via PHP (curl)

Tags: php, curl, apple-push-notifications

Tell me how to send a message by means of a push on the CURL php? This commitment does not work:

```
 $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://gateway.push.apple.com:2195');

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT,'1.pem');

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, "12345");

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"device_tokens": ["........................................."], "aps": {"alert": "test message one!"}}');

 $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);

 echo $curl_scraped_page;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send an Apple Push Notification with CURL.

You are attempting to send a push notification to Apple with an HTTPS request. That can't work, since Apple Push Notifications don't work with HTTP. They only work with a specific binary format over TCP protocol.

> As a provider you communicate with Apple Push Notification service over a binary interface. This interface is a high-speed, high-capacity interface for providers; it uses a streaming TCP socket design in conjunction with binary content. The binary interface is asynchronous

Instead of CURL, you can `stream_context`. You can find many code samples for that.