# PHP apple push notification fail when multiple

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have written a function to send push notifications to iOS devices. It sends pushes to more than 100 devices for now. However sometimes it is not sending push notifications. When I debug through the process I identified based on push notification the whole process fails. but the issues is all push tokens are in valid format. So my initial code was like this.

```
   $certificatePath = CERTIFICATE_PATH . "/".APN_CERTIFICATE_FILE;
   $streamContext = stream_context_create();

   stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $certificatePath);
   stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', APN_PASSWORD);

   $apns = stream_socket_client(APN_HOST . ':' . APN_PORT , $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $streamContext);
    if (!$apns) {
        echo "Failed to connect $err $errstrn";
        return false;
    } 

    $payload = array();
    $payload['aps'] = array('alert' =>$message,'title'=>$title, 'sound' => 'default','data'=>array());
    $payload = json_encode($payload);

    foreach ($pushTokens as $pushToken)
    {
        $pushToken = str_replace(' ', '', $pushToken);
        if(!ctype_xdigit($pushToken))
            continue;

        $apnsMessage = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $pushToken)) . pack        ("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        $rst = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);

    }
    fclose($apns);
```

As a fix I changed the code to different way. I know this code is expensive since it open and close connection for every push notification.

```
$certificatePath = CERTIFICATE_PATH . "/".APN_CERTIFICATE_FILE;
            $streamContext = stream_context_create();

            stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $certificatePath);
            stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', APN_PASSWORD);


            $payload = array();
            $payload['aps'] = array('alert' =>$message,'title'=>$title, 'sound' => 'default','data'=>array());
            $payload = json_encode($payload);

            foreach ($pushTokens as $pushToken)
            {
                $apns = stream_socket_client(APN_HOST . ':' . APN_PORT , $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $streamContext);
                if (!$apns) {
                    echo "Failed to connect $err $errstrn";
                    return false;
                } 

                $pushToken = str_replace(' ', '', $pushToken);
                if(!ctype_xdigit($pushToken))
                    continue;

                $apnsMessage = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $pushToken)) . pack        ("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
                $rst = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
                fclose($apns);
            }
```

I am wondering if it is an issue with `fwrite` or somewhere else. Appreciate if someone can help me with my first method as it is speed, and run with minimum resources.

Comment: Is there any reason why you dont use curl?

Comment: I've never seen anywhere we can use curl for apple push notifications. And this question also says such. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425758/send-apple-push-notifications-via-php-curl